# estoy tratando de conectar Xampp con MySQL workbench

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, xampp, mysql-workbench

Estoy en MySQLWorkbench tratando de conectarlo con Xampp y cuando pongo para ver el Server Status me salta lo que ven en la imagen. Si le pongo "cancelar" me tira que el el siguiente perfil no esta habilitado WMI (windos Managment Instruments). ¿Que hago?

[image]
[El video de Youtube que le pase es lo que estoy siguiendo para poder conectar Xampp con MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf-0PT7q6i4&list=PLAzlSdU-KYwWCVG83AWU-9n9_F6wA8kF7&index=5)

Comment: Hola, si tienes problemas con workbench puedes usar [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/es/products/navicat-for-mysql), es muy recomendable para gestionar bases de datos incluso de otros gestores. También tiene una versión potable, de modo que no tienes problemas de instalación.

Comment: Hola the breaker, yo soy nuevo en lo que tiene que ver programación. Voy a tomar lo de Navicat pero tenes alguna idea de que tengo que hacer con el problema mencione?

Comment: Me imagino cual puede ser el problema, hay una solución en el sitio en ingles que puede ayudarte [Could not connect to targat machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887695/could-not-connect-to-targat-machine)

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo!